# Userform that strikethrough existing cell value and add superscript to the cell

Tags: vba, excel

i'm stuck with this problem and i can seem to find a solution.

i have a sheet in which user can enter new data and confirm them with a commandbutton that protect last entry data. If the user see after the confirmation that he make a mistake he cannot change the answer, because i need to know if he change data after confirmation. So.

I made a userform in which he can enter the cell number (ex : A4) the error number (ex:1, 2, 3, etc..) and select the type of mistake (ex: clarification, inscription mistake, etc..) and then he got a textbox to explain.

What i need and can't do for now is, strikethrough the existing value of the cell, add the error number in superscripts form in the cell (but it should not be strikethrough). Can anyone help me with that?

There's a lot more, but for the rest i could find it by myself

for now this is what I have

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
' Textbox1 is the place where the user enter the Cell he need to change
Range(TextBox1.Value).Select 
' Textbox3 is the error type
If Textbox3.Value = "EI" Then
ActiveCell.Font.strikethrough = True
Else
ActiveCell.Font.strikethrough = False
End If

ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & TextBox2.Value ' textbox2 is the error number

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

I'm stuck there, cuz it strikethrough even the error number, which is not in superscript format.

I almost forgot, it need to strikethrough only if the error type is "EI".

Is that clear?? Sorry if it's not, i've try my best to explain my situation.

Thank again

Comment: Sorry I'm lost... What is your question?

Comment: Sorry about that, i'll try to change the post. I can't find a way to strikethrough only the existing value of the cell chosen by the user, and add the error number in the same cell but that number should not be strikethrough.

Comment: Can you use the interface to apply the strikethrough and all the formatting you want? If you can't with  the interface, then you can't with VBA. If you can with the interface, then you should better describe what you want. Doing the manual formatting while recording a macro also will help you understanding what properties are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're searching for something like this:

1. "finding" the entered cell:

   ActiveSheet.Range(YourTextBox.Text)
2. formatting parts of this cell (enter a start character and a length for formatting):

   With ActiveSheet.Range(YourTextBox.Text).Characters(Start:=2, Length:=len(ActiveSheet.Range(YourTextBox.Text))-1).Font
   .Strikethrough = True
   End With

--> this snippet would format from the second character to the end

It's not all the code you need but I hope it helps...

Comment: the important thing for you is "[cell].Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1)"

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Len(*****)).Font
    .Strikethrough = True
End With
```

You need to check if the Strikethrough text starts in 1.
You can set the Length using `Len` Function or store the initial length to a variable.
Hope it helps.